# The type arguments for method EditorFor cannot be inferred

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Although the page runs fine, I get a lot of errors in my view and no typeahead when doing the following:

```
@using( Html.BeginForm() )
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.EditorFor( x => x.Sausage.WibbleWobble)
```

My View has a model declared as a view model which has 2 properties:

```
@model Blah.WebUI.Models.ViewModels.SausageViewModels.SausageEditViewModel
```

--

```
public class SausageEditViewModel : BaseListViewModel
{
    public Sausage Sausage{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> SausageTypes { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my Sausage:

```
using Blah.Domain.Abstract;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blah.Domain.Objects.Entities
{
    public class Sausage : ISoftDeletable, ITimeStamps, ICreatedBy
    {
        [Key]
        public int SausageID { get; set; }

        public WibbleWobble WibbleWobble {get;set;}
        ...
```

Comment: so where your `EditorFor`? how you try use it?

Comment: Oh dear, sorry about that :) I included the wrong thing... However, it's the same thing for every Razor Html helper... DisplayFor, EditorFor... etc etc.

Comment: Are you sure the View is recognizing your model? Do you get IntelliSense when you type `@Model.`?

Comment: Yes, I do get it for @Model.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988, can you provide `Attribute`? If this a [System.Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx) then it don't have `Key` property. I try create simplest sample, and all work without errors

Comment: Is this clearer? :) It's actually my own property..

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 What type `WibbleWobble`?

Comment: Can you add `Sausage` type definition to your question ?

Comment: Something like that, basically... In reality, it's not a sausage, but an Attribute which has a couple of properties too... Nothing out of the ordinary...

Comment: @Jimmyt1988, i still can't reproduce your errors. Your code seems work: can you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Where is the editorfor implementation?

Comment: It's the default one supplied by .Net MVC 5 I assume. I will spend more time on the question later on.. Thanks for your input.